# Display colored labels in plots with matlab

Tags: data-visualization, matlab

I'm using the following commands to plot a set of points on a 2d map in matlab

labels =  {'label1', ' label2', 'label3',...)
plot(score(:,1),score(:,2), '*')
gname(lables)

Is there a way to choose the color for each label?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Return vector of label handles, then you can set color (as well as other text properties) for all or individual labels.

```
h = gname(lables);
set(h,'color','r') %# set all labels to red
set(h(2),'color','g') %# set 2nd label to green
```